# Stubbing @Async method run as sync

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, junit, mockito

I am trying to test async method with timeout.

When I am calling the method directly the method run asynchronically and throw TimeoutException as expected. But when I stub the method, the method run synchronically and TimeoutException is not thrown. What am i doing wrong?

```
Class A()
{
   @Async
   public Future<Integer> asyncMethod(){
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      return new AsyncResult<>(1);
   }
}
```

```
Class B()
{
  
  A a;

 @Autowired
  B(A a)
 {
     this.a=a;
  }

 public void syncMethod()
 {
     
    Future<Integer>  futureResult = a.asyncMehod();
    // 2sec <  5sec, expect to throw  TimeoutException
    futureCount.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }
}
```

```
Class TestBMockBean()
{
   @MockBean
   A a;
   
   B b;

   @BeforeAll
    public void init()}{
       this.b = new B(a);
}

  // This test failed
   @Test 
   void syncMethod() {
  
 when(a.asyncMethod()).thenAnswer((Answer<AsyncResult<Integer>>) invocation -> {
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      return new AsyncResult<>(0);
    });
  }
  assertThrows(TimeoutException.class,()-> b.syncMethod());
}

}
```

```
Class TestBAutowired()
{
   @Autowired
   B b:

  // This test pass
  @Test //success
   void syncMethod_autowired() {
   assertThrows(TimeoutException.class,()-> b.syncMethod());
  }
}
```

Comment: In TestBMockBean you are stubbing B::syncMethod(). With it, you replace the complete method (incl. the method call that should throw the TimeoutException). So what do you expect, or better: what do you actually want to test?

Comment: @rmunge yes you are right I fixed my example, please see now.